# Scss mixin does not apply styling

Tags: webpack, sass, next.js

## The issue

So I have been trying to get my "px to vw" mixin working in Scss. However, I keep running into an issue where the mixin is not executed and I get the mixin back inside of the inspector when I inspect an h1 for example.

All my functions are imported (from what I can see).

### what I use

I run Scss and it's compiled through Next.js/Webpack.

### The code

First off, my mixin

**Scss:**

```
$design-size: 375;

@mixin get-vw($target) {
  font-size: (($target / $design-size) * 100) * 1vw;
}
```

After defining the mixin, I try to use it on my variable headings, like this:

**Scss**

```
 --heading-1-size: get-vw(32);
```

However, it's returned like this:

[image: The return value]

The Webpack function used (not the entire function, excluding font-rendering):

```
module.exports = {
  trailingSlash: true,
  webpack: (config) => {
    config.module.rules.map((rule) => {
      if (rule.oneOf) {
        rule.oneOf.find((configRule) => {
          if (Array.isArray(configRule.use)) {
            configRule.use.forEach((loaderItem) => {
              const isSassRule = loaderItem.loader && loaderItem.loader.includes('sass-loader')
              if (isSassRule) {
                configRule.use.push({
                  loader: 'sass-resources-loader',
                  options: {
                    resources: [
                      './src/styles/config/_media-queries.scss',
                      './src/styles/config/_fonts.scss'
                    ]
                  },
                })
              }
            })
          }
        })
      }
    })

    return config
  },
}
```

In an ideal situation, the value returned would be a vw value. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The example wouldn't work because you're trying to assign css properties to a css variable using a `@mixin`, what you can do is turn `get-vw` into a `@function` which can be used to set the value for `--heading-1-size`.

```
@function get-vw($target) {
  @return (($target / $design-size) * 100) * 1vw;
}

:root {
  --heading-1-size: #{get-vw(32)};
}
```

Comment: Nice! That works for defining the font-sizes in the `:root`!

Now how could I also make this work for using the same function inside any other component just by running `get-vw(20)`? Thanks!

Comment: You can override the value for a css variable for a element by calling it inside the selector , i.e. `h1 { --heading-1-size: #{get-vw(32)}; font-size: var(--heading-1-size);  }`

Comment: That's not really what I mean. 

When I'm inside let's say the Checkbox.scss file, I want to be able to add custom sizes. I would also want to use it as `padding: get-vw(10) get-vw(20);` etc. :)

Comment: So you can add custom sizes which will cascade down to sub element styles, i.e. `.checkbox { --heading-1-size: #{get-vw(32)}; } .checkbox > label { font-size: var(--heading-1-size); }`, you can use it as `padding: get-vw(10)`, that'll work.

Comment: The issue here is that I would have to define the function every time, right now, there is no way to simply import it and use it globally.

Comment: Could you not define a new css variable globally i.e. `:root { --heading-1-variant-size: #{get-vw(43)} }`?

Comment: I could, but if I need the function for a div width, for example, I can't use the `--heading-1-size` to define it.. I would need the function in order to define the width of that div.